# How to save selected checkbox as an array in ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a simple form where I have the list of checkboxes and I want to send only the checked boxes to the typescript, but when I click on the save button then I face an error **{test: undefined}**

This is my form:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let manager of managers; let i = index">
    <ion-checkbox
      color="primary"
      [(ngModel)]="manager.id"
      value="{{manager.id}}"
      style="margin-right: 10px"
    ></ion-checkbox>
    <ion-label>{{manager.name}}</ion-label>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-button (click)="save()">Save</ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

And this is my typescript:

```
  manager:any;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  save(){
    let data ={
      test: this.manager,
    }
    console.log(data);
  }
```

So, basically, I want that the checked boxes value should be stored in array TS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you can get rid of the value tag inside your checkbox.
`[(ngModel)]` should create the `selected` entry in the object if it is selected after that. You need to check the array when the button is pushed to see if the element has a selected element AND(!) if it's `true` (checked).

After that you can store the value of the selected manager object in an array.

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let manager of managers; let i = index">
    <ion-checkbox
      color="primary"
      [(ngModel)]="manager.selected"
      style="margin-right: 10px"
    ></ion-checkbox>
    <ion-label>{{manager.name}}</ion-label>
  </ion-item>
```

Comment: in console.log it gives error "{test: undefined}"

Comment: could you please share what you did so far?

Comment: I removed the value from the checkbox and added *.selected* in the *ngModel* and nothing else. TS is still the same as my question.

Comment: please consider to log the selected manager and not the whole data object inside of a console.log() - function. see if you get either true or false as a return value.
After that: check inside of your save()-function if the manager is selected (== true) and print out the manager.id.

Comment: Can you please demonstrate in an example based on my scenario?